# UIScrollView pages in the negative direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll, pagination

So I have a UIScrollView set up the following way and for some reason, the scroll view is displayed like this:

```
                  Phone Screen

                ---------------
---------------|---------------|
---------------|---------------|
---------------|---------------|
---------------|----Content----|
---------------|---------------|
---------------|---------------|
---------------|---------------|
---------------|---------------|
                ---------------
```

My goal is to have the user scroll to the right, like below:

```
  Phone Screen

 ---------------
|---------------|---------------
|---------------|---------------
|---------------|---------------
|----Content----|---------------
|---------------|---------------
|---------------|---------------
|---------------|---------------
|---------------|---------------
 ---------------
```

Here's how the scroll view is set up (this is a bit simplified, but accurate):

```
CGFrame frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width*2, self.bounds.size.height);
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
scrollView.propertyN = bool; //E.g. pagingEnabled, bounces, clipsToBounds, etc.

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:someImage];
imageView.frame = frame;

[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm sure I'm making some extremely basic mistake in my setup of the scroll view but can't seem to spot it.

Comment: It can only be (a) the contentOffset is being set to x=bounds.size.width, y=0, or (b) some descendant of the scroll view --subview or subview's subview, etc. -- has a frame with negative x position, or (c) some other reason I can't think of.

Comment: @danh - I've checked and the contentOffset is set to (0,0), and the only subview is this image view I'm adding and it's origin is definitely positive for both x and y.

Comment: Then I'm stumped.  It is a little strange to set imageView.frame equal to its parent's frame (though I don't think thats a problem here since it's origin is 0,0). And if the image is the only subview and the contentSize is 2x the scroll view width, don't you want your image to be that wide too?

Comment: @danh - Shouldn't the width of the subview be equal to the width of the scroll view, and the contentSize be a multiple of the width of the subview?

Comment: contentSize is usually a size large enough to encompass the content of the scrollView.  Setting it to 2WxH usually implies that the first generation of descendant(s) -- in your case, the image -- occupies that size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could the the `origin` for `self.view.frame` be offscreen (e.g. `-self.bounds.width`)?

I'd try starting with simple code and building back up to what you want.  Here's some simple code that's similar to the code above that you can throw in a blank project to convince yourself that the code you posted isn't the likely culprit:

```
  CGFloat width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
  CGFloat height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,width,height);
  CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(width*2, height);

  UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
  scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
  scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

  UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
  view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width,0.0f,width,height)];
  view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

  [scrollView addSubview:view1];
  [scrollView addSubview:view2];
  [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```